# Want to insert the data one table conditional combination with other one table in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

How to insert data into one table as compared to another one table wrt some conditions?

Structures of both the table are same.

```
insert into x.Summing (a, b, c, d, e, f) 
values 
    (select a, b, c, d, e, sum(f) 
     from
         ((select a, b, c, d, e, f from x.draft 
           where d = 1 
             and substr(A, -2, 2) in (select ODE from x.ram
                                      where city = 'KT'))
          union all
          (select a, b, c, d, e, sum(f) from x.draft 
           where d != 1 
             and substr(A, -2, 2) in (select ODE from x.ram
                                      where city = 'KT'))
    )
group by a, b, c, d, e;
```

But I'm getting this error :

> SQL Error: ORA-00936: missing expression
> 00936. 00000 -  "missing expression"

Comment: You are selecting `where d=1` then make union all with `d!=1`, so you are finally filtering null `d1`. All this union and subquery seems unneccesary, but maybe I missed something or perhaps you simplified your query.

Answer (score 0):

Query you posted is invalid; `values` should be removed (as you aren't inserting separate values, but result of a `select` statement).

Also, query itself is invalid. It is kind of difficult to guess what you're doing without sample data and dummy column names, but the 2nd `union` query also requires `group by` clause as it sums `f` so all other non-aggregated columns have to be put into `group by`.

Rewritten, this *should* (can't test it) be OK as far as syntax is concerned.

```
INSERT INTO x.Summing (a,
                       b,
                       c,
                       d,
                       e,
                       f)
     SELECT a,
            b,
            c,
            d,
            e,
            SUM (f)
       FROM (
               (SELECT a,
                       b,
                       c,
                       d,
                       e,
                       f
                  FROM x.draft
                 WHERE     d = 1
                       AND SUBSTR (A, -2, 2) IN (SELECT ODE
                                                   FROM x.ram
                                                  WHERE city = 'KT'))
               UNION ALL
               (  SELECT a,
                         b,
                         c,
                         d,
                         e,
                         SUM (f)
                    FROM x.draft
                   WHERE     d != 1
                         AND SUBSTR (A, -2, 2) IN (SELECT ODE
                                                     FROM x.ram
                                                    WHERE city = 'KT')
                GROUP BY a,
                         b,
                         c,
                         d,
                         e)
            )
   GROUP BY a,
            b,
            c,
            d,
            e;
```

Answer (score 0):

Ypou have missed that the comand is INSERT INTO SELECT

so you can do

```
insert into x.Summing (a,b,c,d,e,f)  
 select  a,b,c,d,e,sum(f) 
 from
    (
        (Select  a,b,c,d,e,f from x.draft 
        where  d=1 and SUBSTR(A,-2,2) IN (SELECT ODE FROM x.ram
                                                 WHERE city='KT'))
    union all
    (Select  a,b,c,d,e,sum(f) from x.draft 
    where  d!=1 and SUBSTR(A,-2,2) IN (SELECT ODE FROM x.ram
                                                 WHERE city='KT'))
)
group by a,b,c,d,e;
```

Answer (score 0):

The only difference between the two sub-queries is the filter on `d = 1` and `d != 1`. You can combine those two into a single condition of `d = 1 OR d != 1` and then further to `d IS NOT NULL`. Once you do that then the `UNION` is unnecessary:

```sql
insert into x.Summing (a,b,c,d,e,f)
  select  a,b,c,d,e,sum(f)
  from    x.draft 
  where   d IS NOT NULL
  and     SUBSTR(A,-2,2) IN (SELECT ODE
                             FROM   x.ram
                             WHERE  city='KT')
  group by a,b,c,d,e;
```

Apart from that you have a syntax error with the `VALUES` keyword (which is not necessary when using `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...`).